# SQL: sorting child rows under parent row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in my SQL Server database.

```
MenuID  MenuText    ParentMenu     MenuOrder        MenuLevel
-------------------------------------------------------------
1   Home                0              1                0
2   Administrator       0              2                0
3   Groups              2              1                1
4   Users               2              2                1
5   Permissions         2              3                1
6   Test Level2         3              1                2
7   Test Level3         6              1                3
```

I want to sort this table rows like this:

- `Home`, `Administrator` are MenuLevel 0 items.
- MenuLevel 1 items will be under its top level menus according to their `ParentMenu` column which points to the parent `MenuID`. The child items will be sorted according to their `MenuOrder` column.

I tried so many things, but couldn't get the idea how it will be done using query.

Comment: Kindly include the expected result.

Comment: Common Table Expressions (CTEs) will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/efd82/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        DisplayOrder = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentMenu ORDER BY MenuOrder) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM Test
    WHERE
        ParentMenu = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.MenuID,
        t.MenuText,
        t.ParentMenu,
        t.MenuOrder,
        t.MenuLevel,
        DisplayOrder = c.DisplayOrder + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ParentMenu ORDER BY t.MenuOrder) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM Cte c
    INNER JOIN Test t
        ON c.MenuID = t.ParentMenu 
)
SELECT
    MenuID,
    MenuText,
    ParentMenu,
    MenuOrder,
    MenuLevel
FROM cte
ORDER BY DisplayOrder
```

**Result:**

```
| MenuID |      MenuText | ParentMenu | MenuOrder | MenuLevel |
|--------|---------------|------------|-----------|-----------|
|      1 |          Home |          0 |         1 |         0 |
|      2 | Administrator |          0 |         2 |         0 |
|      3 |        Groups |          2 |         1 |         1 |
|      6 |   Test Level2 |          3 |         1 |         2 |
|      7 |   Test Level3 |          6 |         1 |         3 |
|      4 |         Users |          2 |         2 |         1 |
|      5 |   Permissions |          2 |         3 |         1 |
```